# Stuck trying to fetch data from MongoDB into Gatsby using `gatsby-source-mongodb`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, graphql-js, gatsby

So there seems to be almost no detailed documentation on how to do this. Basically all I have to guide me is [this](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-mongodb/). I've followed it up to *Mapping mediatype feature*, at which point I've become stuck. It gives one example: fetching data from a collection for the purpose of using markdown. But this isn't what I'm trying to achieve.

Basically what I want to do is import a couple of collections from Mongo, which I intend to pull into my Gatsby app — possibly using GraphQL.

So far, this is what I've done to my `gatsby-config.js`:

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-mongodb`,
      options: {
        dbName: `REDACTED`,
        collection: `articles`,
        map: { articles: { /* WHAT DO I DO HERE? */ } }
      },
      server: { address: `REDACTED`, port: 43532 },
      auth: { user: `REDACTED`, password: `REDACTED` },
      extraParams: { replicaSet: `test-shard-0`, ssl: true, authSource: `admin` }
    }
```

After this I then need find a way of querying the imported collection, which I have no real idea how to do.

Many thanks in advance for any help offered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, one of the main errors in my question was that I was putting `server`, `auth`, and `extraParams` outside of the `options` object.

The below config enabled me to get Atlas working correctly:

```
{
    resolve: `gatsby-source-mongodb`,
    options: {
        dbName: `your-database-name`,
        collection: [`yourCollection1`, `yourCollection2`],
        server: { address: 'cluster0-shard-00-01-XXXX.mongodb.net', port: 27017},
        auth: { user: 'yourUserName', password: 'yourPassword' },
        extraParams: { replicaSet: 'Cluster0-shard-0', ssl: true, authSource: `admin`, retryWrites: true }
    }      
}
```

Note: The replicaSet parameter must match the beginning of your address (as shown in the example). Also you can find your cluster URL by clicking the `CONNECT` button on your cluster's main info panel at cloud.mongodb.com. (Picture below)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The docs seem pretty clear.

> Basically what I want to do is import a couple of collections from Mongo,

```
// In your gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-mongodb`,
      options: { dbName: `local`, collection: [`documents`, `vehicles`] },
    },
  ],
}
```

> After this I then need find a way of querying the imported collection

```
query {
  allMongodbLocalDocuments {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        url
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: The query `allMongodbLocalDocuments` might differ for your case based on your `dbName`. But you should be able to find the available queries in GraphiQL (`http://localhost:8000/___graphql`)

Now you should be able to test the above query in GraphiQL.

Then, have a look at the gatsby [using mongodb example](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/examples/using-mongodb/gatsby-node.js) project. In `gatsby-node.js` they use the above query to then create a page for each node in the query from the template at `./src/templates/item.js`

Comment: Are you able to test the query in GraphiQL?

Comment: Thanks for your response :) I had to get a friend to help me with it. Basically I had set up the plugin incorrectly in the config file. As you can see I put server, auth, extraParams outside of options. I've got it working now and with GraphiQL too. My friend will be posting a detailed answer soon to explain exactly what needs to be added into the config file in order to connect to MongoDB Atlas.

Comment: @JossClassey can you show your solution as I haven't got it working.